# How do I begin working on the Project Tango?

Tags: android, android-ndk, google-project-tango

after a couple of weeks I have been unable to get the android set of tools to a functioning level with c++ before and have been given the opportunity of using a project tango, and though that sounds awesome and wondrous and would open a world of opportunity for working with VR... I feel like I am stuck at step -4.  My understanding is limited, so bear with me.
I stumbled upon the PCL built for running algorithms on point cloud data, it was open source and appeared like a wonderful solution, it is written in C++ and I have a mild understanding of both c++ and java.
I have tried using Eclipse and the NDK and actually managed to get a project 'deployed' to the tango, however upon attempting to edit any file in the project, java or c++, it breaks and will never deploy again.
Now I am trying to use Android Studio, and after following about 5 conflicting tutorials on 'how to get C++/ndk working in android studio' I have yet to get a working environment.
So here is my question, and we can start at step one, any help is appreciated. How does one get c++ and the PCL working on a google project tango, is there a better way for someone of my skill level?  The end result is a mapped 3d space with the project tango, with exportable data sets of manageable size. I have seen it done in demos on youtube, but thus far, like i said, I am stuck on step -4.

Comment: I tried like mad with Android Studio, as I know Eclipse and do not relish it's company - I failed miserably and returned to Eclipse - for me, the unsurmountable problem was trying to get Gradle to bring in the Tango shared lib.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we are working on converting all project to android studio based, for now, here is the walk around to get you started:

1. Open Android Studio, import the project from the repo you just cloned.
2. Take the motion-tracking-jni-example as the example, copy tango-gl-render, tango-service-sdk, and third-party into the motion-tracking-jni-example/app/src.
3. Run ndk-build in the motion-tracking-jni-example/app/src/main folder.
4. ndk will generate the libs folder, rename it to jniLibs.
5. Go to Android Studio, in build.gradle(Module:app) file, add line 'sourceSets.main.jni.srcDirs = []' to the defaultConfig section.
6. Just click the run button in Android Studio.

What we did here is basically disabled the Android Stdio's JNI compile and manually built it using ndk.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I also found this blog very helpful. [link](http://www.shaneenishry.com/blog/2014/08/17/ndk-with-android-studio/)

Answer (score 0):

Start with unity3d, its easy to get a working demo with a week with Unity3D.
And support is very good, documentation is top notch.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score -1):

[Tango NDK Tutorial](https://github.com/sjfricke/Tango-C-NDK-Tutorial/tree/master/Section_04_Project) Will help but the basic layout is

1. Setup a new project
2. Create your Java activity
3. Create a JNI file to bridge Java to the C++
4. Create your C++ logic
5. Setup your Makefiles and Gradle (probably the most annoying part)